# Apply css to a div and class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to put external CSS for the given codes as it is a `div` with a `class`:

```
<div class="adv_post_container nolinks" id="activity-post-container" style="display: block;">
```

is it

```
#activity-post-container.adv_post_container.nolinks
```

OR

```
#activity-post-container .adv_post_container.nolinks
```

Or is there another way?

By the way, what is this called? I know `div` inside `div` is called "nested." What is this called?

Comment: It's just called an HTML element, or a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `attribute concatenation`. Your example uses a very specific rule, hard to overwrite. It is a good idea to style the elements by using a `tag` or `class` attribute and keep `id` only for very specific styles.

If you dive a little bit into CSS specificity, you will learn a lot about how to use attributes and what specificity do they have.

You can find a very good explanation with examples here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score -1):

First, decide which you want to use to target, class or ID and use one of the options below:

- ID you target with "`#`": `#activity-post-container`
- Class you target with "`.`": `.adv_post_container`

Comment: #activity-post-container is sufficient to target

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Gerard - extended the reply to make it clear - thank you!

Comment: @StephenNollan - you're welcome - if you're happy with the answer, can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of these,
ID and Class.
"#" If You Target Your ID    #activity-post-container or
"." If You Target Your Class .adv_post_container